# Como hacer funcionar un metodo que se encuentra en un @click dentro de un innerHTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js, innerhtml

En el siguiente código estoy cambiando el HTML que hay en un elemento de una tabla. Concretamente, le estoy pasando un botón con una llamada a función, pero la llamada no funciona. ¿Sugerencias?

**Código**:

```
    _method(){
        var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')
        for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i+=2){
            tr[i].innerHTML = "<button @click='_hola()'>Visualizar</button>" // no funciona la llamada
        }
    }

    _hola(){
      console.log('hola') // no se muestra por pantalla
    }
```

Comment: No puedes injectar *código  Vue* en el documento y esperar que funcione, Vue usa las plantillas que creas para generar HTML "real". Esa lógica deberías añadirla como parte de la plantilla, quizá con un "if" para seleccionar si mostrar un botón o no

Answer (score -1):

Creo que quieres mostrar una colección de datos en una tabla, para esto es más óptimo de esta forma ([imagen original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcwDz.png)):

Básicamente para recorrer una colección de datos puedes utilizar la directiva v-for dentro del template, la cual renderizara los datos, en la estructura HTML que desees, facilitando capturar el ID u dato que prefieras pasar como parámetro a una función o una redirección.

@Pablo También se pueden hace condiciones dentro del v-for con v-if; para poner una imagen, si la URL de la imagen está en una variable externa o viene del API puede usar una etiqueta `<img :src="data.img">`.

```
<template>
  <div id="App">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(data, index) in collect" :key="index">
          <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.name }}</td> 
          <td>
            <button @click='_hola()'>Visualizar</button>
          </td>
        <tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
      return {
        collect: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Yield' },
          { id: 2, name: 'Lopez' }, 
          { id: 3, name: 'Obrador' },
        ]
      }
    },
    mounted: function() {
    },
    methods: {
      _hola() {
        console.log('Hola');
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Es una tabla donde los datos se consiguen a través de una llamada a api. Bien, pues si se da cierta condición, tengo que cambiar ciertos valores por una imagen. Lo he intentado hacer dinámicamente, pero el método no responde.

Comment: En la tabla hay 139 elementos (por ahora, puede que en un futuro hayan más o menos, dado que los datos vienen por api, como he comentado anteriormente). No puedo poner una etiqueta <button> directamente en el HTML. La idea es, crear el botón dinámicamente con un método asociado.

Comment: @sergioriverafl aunque esta respuesta puede servir de guía para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una descripción de lo que hacen o cómo resuelven el problema, se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle y descripción. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @Pablo También se pueden hace condiciones dentro del v-for con v-if; para poner una imagen, si la URL de la imagen está en una variable externa o viene del API puede usar una etiqueta <img :src="data.img">